# How to print the data values of an object?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I have created a class employee in Java, where each object of the class stands for a staff. The objects take 3 parameters - Name, Dept. and Salary. The program looks like this:

```
public class employee
{
    String name;
    int salary;
    String dept;
    employee staff1 = new employee("x","IT",100000);
    employee staff2 = new employee("y", "HR", 200000);
    public employee(String n, String d, int s)
    {
        this.name= n;
        this.salary= s;
        this.dept = d;
    }   
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        
    }
    public void Display()
    {
            
    
        
        
    }
}
```

I want to make a method (the Display method in the code) which takes the object name as a parameter (the code does not have a parameter) and returns (or prints) its data values. Please also tell me what should come in the main method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to inform you that the above design is wrong. An employee object itself shouldn't contain 2 other employee objects that always get created with the object itself. That will only lead to infinite recursion and object creation and have your program crash once the memory is filled up with employee objects. If for every employee created you automatically create 2 more employee objects, then those 2 will automatically create 2 employees each for 4 total, those 4 will then create 8 objects, then 16 etc pp.

Comment: I haven't created an object employee inside employee class. The employee class contains 2 objects staff1 and staff2. @OHGODSPIDERS

Comment: but both the objects belong to the employee class. Can I declare them outside it and will it work?

Comment: No, you have. `employee staff1 = new employee("x","IT",100000);` <- This will create an employee object for your field and get called on object initialization. Trust me. This can't and will not work because of the reasons I explained above. And it also makes absolutely no logical sense. An employee doesn't need to know about other employee objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this -

```
public class employee {
String name;
int salary;
String dept;

public employee(String n, String d, int s) {
    this.name = n;
    this.salary = s;
    this.dept = d;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    employee staff1 = new employee("x", "IT", 100000);
    employee staff2 = new employee("y", "HR", 200000);
    Display(staff1);
    Display(staff2);
}

public static void Display(employee object) {

    System.out.println("name='" + object.name + '\'' +
            ", salary=" + object.salary +
            ", dept='" + object.dept + '\'');
}
}
```